# What is Angular 2 RC angular2-in-memory-web-api?

Tags: angular

What is angular2-in-memory-web-api? I've seen references to it in the angular.io documentation but my code seems to work without it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's used for demos only:

For example the `get heroes scenario` would work without webapi, just loading demo data from JSON file, but we want to save data too. We can't save changes to a JSON file. We need a web API server.

The `in-memory web api` is not part of the Angular core. It's an optional service in its own `angular2-in-memory-web-api` library that we installed with npm (see package.json) and registered for module loading by SystemJS (see systemjs.config.js)

The in-memory web API gets its data from a custom application class with a `createDb()` method that returns a map whose keys are collection names and whose values are arrays of objects in those collections.

Answer (score 7):

Here the Javadoc from the [InMemoryDataService on Github](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api):

> Simulate the behavior of a RESTy web api
>      backed by the simple in-memory data store provided by the injected InMemoryDataService service.
>    [...]

You can use the API to **create a demo application** in Angular2.
The service provides an API which let you simulate a REST-API. It's only an optional package and your app will work without it.